# Setting a time for flicker animation on img

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code to make my logo flicker on my website. But It becomes annoying when it continues to flicker while browsing, how can I set a time to allow it to flicker for something like the first 15seconds on page load, then stops?

**JS code I'm using:**

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    var t;
    const fparam = 100;
    const uparam = 100;
    window.flickr = function(){
        if(Math.round(Math.random())){
            $("#logodcoi").css("visibility","hidden");
            t = setTimeout('window.unflickr()',uparam);
        }
        else
            t = setTimeout('window.flickr()',fparam);
    }
    window.unflickr = function(){
        if(Math.round(Math.random())){
            $("#logodcoi").css("visibility","visible");
            t = setTimeout('window.flickr()',fparam);
        }
        else
            t = setTimeout('window.unflickr()',uparam);
    }

    t = setTimeout('window.flickr()',fparam);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a counter, which you then use to decide whether you want to set another timeout. As a side note, you should never add functions to window and then passing a string to `setTimeout`. Always just pass the function itself:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var t;
    var amount = 0;
    const fparam = 100;
    const uparam = 100;

    function timeout(f, t) {   // this function delegates setTimeout
        if(amount++ < 150) {   // and checks the amount already (un)flickered
             setTimeout(f, t); // (150 * 100 ms = 15 s)
        }
    }

    var flickr = function(){
        if(Math.round(Math.random())){
            $("#logodcoi").css("visibility","hidden");
            t = timeout(unflickr,uparam);
        }
        else
            t = timeout(flickr,fparam);
    };

    var unflickr = function(){
        if(Math.round(Math.random())){
            $("#logodcoi").css("visibility","visible");
            t = timeout(flickr,fparam);
        }
        else
            t = timeout(unflickr,uparam);
    };

    t = timeout(flickr,fparam);
});
```

Comment: Awesome! For some reason, though. It seems like after every other page refresh, after the time out - the logo disappears completely after time out?

Comment: @cam77: Perhaps it ends with a `flickr` so that the end state is "invisible". You could make it such that when `amount === 150` then show the logo.

Comment: I see. Sorry, how could I write that? Something after;  if(amount++ < 150) { and like '(amount === 150) display: #logodcoi'?

Comment: @cam77: After the `if` clause in `timeout`, add e.g. `else if(amount === 150) { unflickr(); }`.

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using jquery, you could use the following, if I remember correctly, all the stuff I use below has been in jquery since 1.0, so you should be good:

```
counter = 1;
function hideOrShow(){
             $(".classToSelect").animate({"opacity": "toggle"}, 100);
             counter = counter +1;
             if (counter >= 21) clearInterval(flickerInterval);
}
flickerInterval = setInterval(hideOrShow, 100);
```

Change the selector, animation duration, and variable names to whatever you fancy/need.

Comment: do your maths on the number of times you want it to flicker and set the limit accordingly (I just pulled 21 out of thick air), so that the last iteration toggles the opacity to 1 and not 0! ;)