# Setting flicker animation timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is deriving from 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369174/setting-a-time-for-flicker-animation-on-img'

I'm unable to figure out how to set the timeout of my flicker animation to timeout and display my image consistently. Right now - it flickers all nice as supposed to, but every other page visit/browser refresh, after the animation the image isn't displayed anymore. It's my logo, so I want it to flicker (like a dimmed sign) and after it flickers for a bit, it just displays normally.

Here's my code I'm trying:

```
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
    var t;
    var amount = 0;
    const fparam = 100;
    const uparam = 100;

    function timeout(f, t) {   // this function delegates setTimeout
        if(amount++ < 50) {   // and checks the amount already (un)flickered
             setTimeout(f, t); // (150 * 100 ms = 15 s)
        }
    else if(amount === 50) { unflickr(); }
    }

    var flickr = function(){
        if(Math.round(Math.random())){
            $("#logodcoi").css("visibility","hidden");
            t = timeout(unflickr,uparam);
        }
        else
            t = timeout(flickr,fparam);

    };


    var unflickr = function(){
        if(Math.round(Math.random())){
            $("#logodcoi").css("visibility","visible");
            t = timeout(flickr,fparam);
        }
        else
            t = timeout(unflickr,uparam);
    };

    t = timeout(flickr,fparam);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image disappearing is due to the `Math.random()` call  in `unflickr` not returning an even number, which is then hiding the image.

To fix this, I've amended your code slightly, to check the number of iterations already completed, and add another condition in the `timeout` function to clear the timeout (which should perform better as the original meant the code would have run forever while the page was displayed which would have eaten memory) and then display the image when passed the number of desired flicks:

```
var t;
var amount = 0;
var maxFlickrs = 50
const fparam = 100;
const uparam = 100;

function timeout(f, t) { // this function delegates setTimeout
    if (amount++ < maxFlickrs ) { // and checks the amount already (un)flickered
        setTimeout(f, t); // (150 * 100 ms = 15 s)
    }
    else if (amount === maxFlickrs ) {
        unflickr();
    }
    else {
        // had number of iterations set in maxFlickrs, stop flickering and display image.
        clearTimeout(t);
        $("#logodcoi").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
}

var flickr = function() {
    if (Math.round(Math.random())) {
        $("#logodcoi").css("visibility", "hidden");
        t = timeout(unflickr, uparam);
    }
    else
        t = timeout(flickr, fparam);

};

var unflickr = function() {
    if (Math.round(Math.random())) {
        $("#logodcoi").css("visibility", "visible");
        t = timeout(flickr, fparam);
    }
    else
        t = timeout(unflickr, uparam);
};

t = timeout(flickr, fparam);
```

[**Fiddle to show it working**](http://jsfiddle.net/xWDFu/)

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel? You will need to include jquery UI for this however: http://jqueryui.com/download

```
$('the element in question').effect("pulsate", { times:3 }, 1000);
```

Comment: Pulsate is an even fading in and out of the element. If you check the fiddle in my question you'll see the element should flicker between hidden/visible for a random period before being fully visible when the animation has finished.

Comment: Apologies, I should have read the question better. You solved the problem though right?

Comment: Think so, unless the OP says otherwise ;)